# Flot tooltip on hover

Tags: php, graph, tooltip, flot

I have the following code showing the graph using Flot. I want to get the mouse hover to show a tooltip with the values of days/quota

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
$FundName=$_POST["FundName"];
$mes=$_POST["mes"];
$cnpj=$_POST["cnpj"];
 ?>


<?php
$query = "SELECT Dia, Quota FROM CDVM WHERE Competence='$mes' AND FundName='$FundName' AND Quota > 0";
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 ?>

<?php
    $points = "";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $quota = str_replace(',', '.', $row['Quota']);
        $points .= "[{$row['Dia']}, {$quota}], ";
    }
    $points = rtrim($points, ", ");
?>

 <div id="placeholder" style="width:500px;height:200px"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $.plot("#placeholder", [[ <?php echo $points ?> ],
            {
                series: {
                    lines: {
                        show: true
                    },
                    points: {
                        show: true
                    }
                },
                grid: {
                    hoverable: true,
                    clickable: true
                }
            });

            $("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
                if (item) {
                    if (previousPoint != item.dataIndex) {

                        previousPoint = item.dataIndex;

                        $("#tooltip").remove();
                        var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
                        y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);

                        showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY,
                            "Dia=" + x + ", Quota=" + y);
                    }
                } else {
                    $("#tooltip").remove();
                    previousPoint = null;            
                }
            });

            function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
                $("<div id='tooltip'>" + contents + "</div>").css({
                    position: "absolute",
                    display: "none",
                    top: y + 5,
                    left: x + 5,
                    border: "1px solid #fdd",
                    padding: "2px",
                    "background-color": "#fee",
                    opacity: 0.80
                }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
            }
        });
</script>
```

I alo have call the jquery from flot website in the head of the file. I just have problems copying the whole code on to here.
Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create an element for the tooltip (a span or div), and then bind plothover to it. I used the example on their website "Interacting with the data points" on my own website.

The below code uses the showTooltip function to create the tooltip div, triggered with the call to .bind("plothover").  This enables hovering to trigger the tooltip and populate it with the relevant data item.

Here's my code modified for a complete working version.  Just make sure your database string is in there before "while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))"

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <?php
        $points = "";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $quota = str_replace(',', '.', $row['Quota']);
            $points .= "[{$row['Dia']}, {$quota}], ";
        }
        $points = rtrim($points, ", ");
    ?>
    <div id="placeholder" style="width:500px;height:200px"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $.plot("#placeholder", [[ <?php echo $points ?> ]],
                {
                    series: {
                        lines: {
                            show: true
                        },
                        points: {
                            show: true
                        }
                    },
                    grid: {
                        hoverable: true,
                        clickable: true
                    }
                });

                $("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
                    if (item) {
                        if (previousPoint != item.dataIndex) {

                            previousPoint = item.dataIndex;

                            $("#tooltip").remove();
                            var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
                            y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);

                            showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY,
                                "Dia=" + x + ", Quota=" + y);
                        }
                    } else {
                        $("#tooltip").remove();
                        previousPoint = null;            
                    }
                });

                function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
                    $("<div id='tooltip'>" + contents + "</div>").css({
                        position: "absolute",
                        display: "none",
                        top: y + 5,
                        left: x + 5,
                        border: "1px solid #fdd",
                        padding: "2px",
                        "background-color": "#fee",
                        opacity: 0.80
                    }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
                }
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should I add that code into the function that draws the graph?

Comment: I've edited my post to be specific to your use case.  Replace this code with all my code and it should work just fine.  You can play with the settings listed on the flot website to make alterations to the presentation. $(function () { var dataset1 = ;

$.plot($("#placeholder"), [ dataset1 ]);
});

Comment: Inside a <script> block, either in the <head> block, or right before the closing </body> tag... or in the same place you've currently got the code I said to replace.  You literally just need to switch out what you put with what I put.

Comment: Hey Karl, first of all, thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it. I need to get this working ASAP, so your help is really appreciated. However, I copied your code above, and replaced my code that draws the graph with it, and now all my graph won't show...

Comment: I've updated my answer to a complete working version, which I've tested locally.  Just copy that as-is and as long as your database connection is working, it should be fine.

Comment: I did as you mentioned, and it sitll won«t draw. You can have a look over here:
http://euotm.net/

And yes, the mysql $query and $result, are above the code you sent me. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any test values I can enter into the form?  When I submit it, it's blank and so there's no data between the square braces here: $.plot("#placeholder", [  ],

Comment: OH yes, sorry. First field write 1-S and select that name. The date is correct and CNPJ you can leave empty. Does nothing for now.

Comment: Haha, okay, I think we're there now.  I've modified my code to allow for two things: 1. Nested plot points, and 2. The fact that your Portuguese way of using a comma in a decimal number breaks the array... so there's a str_replace to convert this to use a dot instead.  I've tested that on my machine and it's working.  Let me know how you get on :)

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to mention that part. Unfortunately, though, it shows up blank...I edit my initial post on here to show you my exact code. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: DAMN!! My fault.  I copied a line incorrectly.  There should be two "]" after <?php echo $points ?>... so that line should read: `$.plot("#placeholder", [[ <?php echo $points ?> ]],`

Comment: I don't know how I also missed that..BUT...IT WORKS!!! Thank you SO MUCH! You have been great! :)

Comment: Glad it's working Tom :).  Do you mind accepting my answer by clicking the tick on the left hand side please?  Thanks.

Comment: And done :) Thanks so much for the help. I have another question though, if you woulnd't mind helping me. As you saw, the page has 3 graphs. I got them all to work, but now that I add the tooltip code to the other graphs, they don't draw up. I changed the variables to fit the different graph, yet nothing. Any tips on that?

Comment: I just added another answer with explanaiton of my problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the other graphics don't draw because of the following code:

```
        while($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3))
    {
        $quota3 = $row3['TDC'];
        $points3 = "[{$row3['Dia']}, {$tdc}], ";
    }
    $points3 = rtrim($points, ", ");
```

I changed the variables to $name3...
An example of a TDC value in the DB is as follows:4.504.801,65
Could it be with comma/dot?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, 100% that's why!  You cannot send any commas in the value for a number as it's interpreted as a new element in the array.  You probably should be storing numbers in the database with any sort of locale-based number formatting.  All decimal numbers should be stored as 1234567.89.  We're in the danger now of reverse-engineering "bad numbers".  It may be best to correct this at database level.

Comment: Unforunately I'm not responsible for the database...just need the graphs to show...what could I do on the code to fix that?

Comment: Replace your `$quota3=` line with this: `$tdc = str_replace(".", "", $row3['TDC']); $tdc = str_replace(",", ".", $tdc));` That code will remove all dots, then convert the comma to a dot.

Comment: Alright...I found the mistakes, and got this to work, but it rounds up the number unfortunately...insteal of 4.5....it just shows 4.0..beh....

Comment: Oops, just checked - looks like I had an extra ) in there. But surely the number should be 4504801.65, not 4.5...? After doing the two str_replace commands, what output do you get from `echo $tdc;`?

Comment: Sorry, Value I get is  4,440,833,87 (which is correct), but the graph shows 4.0

Comment: If you want, type 1-s and select the name, the date set to default, and submit. See the results..

Comment: I can't understand why that's happening.  If the original number is `1.161.768,01`, then my code should first remove all the dots to make `1161768,01`, and then convert the comma to a dot `1161768.01`.  The only error in my last code looks like the inclusion of an extra `)` in line 2.  Can you post the TDC code that you have there please?

Answer (score 0):

```
       <?php
    $points3 = "";
    while($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3))
    {

        $tdc3 = str_replace('.', ',', $row3['TDC']);
        $points3 .= "[{$row3['Dia']}, {$tdc3}], ";
    }
    $points3 = rtrim($points3, ". ");
     echo $points3;
?>

<div id="placeholder3" style="width:500px;height:200px"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $.plot("#placeholder3", [[ <?php echo $points3 ?> ]],
            {
                series: {
                    lines: {
                        show: true
                    },
                    points: {
                        show: true
                    }
                },
                grid: {
                    hoverable: true,
                    clickable: true
                }
            });

            $("#placeholder3").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
                if (item) {
                    if (previousPoint != item.dataIndex) {

                        previousPoint = item.dataIndex;

                        $("#tooltip3").remove();
                        var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2);
                       var y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(4);

                        showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY,
                            "Dia=" + x + ", TDC=" + y);
                    }
                } else {
                    $("#tooltip3").remove();
                    previousPoint = null;            
                }
            });

            function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
                $("<div id='tooltip3'>" + contents + "</div>").css({
                    position: "absolute",
                    display: "none",
                    top: y + 5,
                    left: x + 5,
                    border: "1px solid #fdd",
                    padding: "2px",
                    "background-color": "#fee",
                    opacity: 0.80
                }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I've corrected your code... Check the two lines as per my original comment.

Comment: I edited your code directly but it's not saved... says it needs a peer review. Grrr!  Here are the two lines you need to include, which replaces your `$tdc3 = ` line:

Comment: `$tdc3 = str_replace('.', '', $row3['TDC']);`

Comment: `$tdc3 = str_replace(',', '.', $tdc3);`

Comment: Awesome Karl! Thank you so much for all your help!! I really appreciate it!

Comment: It looks good :)  I've just had a look now.  You need to add the same lines to the _Gráfico de Quota_ chart too.  Good luck with the rest of your project!